# Anaconda UnsatisfiableError installing QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, geotiff-tiff, proj, anaconda

If I run `conda install -c conda-forge qgis=2.18.2` from my Ubuntu bash environment, I obtain the following error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - geotiff
  - qgis 2.18.2* -> libspatialite -> proj4 4.9.3
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

The issue is apparently a result of geotiff having a dependency on proj4 4.9.2, whereas QGIS has a dependency on 4.9.3.

If I want to install QGIS in my Anaconda environment, is there any way to achieve this without removing geotiff? I would like to keep its functionality.